# Teamcity Failed to perform checkout on agent

Tags: git, azure, teamcity, repo

I have azure repos to teamcity using SSH key based authentiation and connection is successful at VCS root.

when i ran build pipeine getting below error, could any one please help me here

[Updating sources] Failed to perform checkout on agent: '"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe" -c credential.helper= fetch --progress --recurse-submodules=no origin +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*' command failed. exit code: 128 stderr: bash: line 1: /dev/tty: No such device or address error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1) fatal: could not read Password for 'https://GDFedExGround@gdfedexground.visualstudio.com': No such file or directory

I have also added the parameter teamcity.git.use.native.ssh = true but still no go

Teamcity version I am using:  TeamCity Professional 2020.1.1

Git version: 2.43.0

Soluction for my issue i am expecting